# VB.Net / HttpWebRequest memory leak

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have the following code, executing +- every 1 second (it is used for position tracking):

```
Dim httpClientRequest As HttpWebRequest
httpClientRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(New Uri(REPORTURL & "/tracker.php?id=" & ourGUID.ToString)), HttpWebRequest)
httpClientRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
httpClientRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate Or DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.None
httpClientRequest.CachePolicy = New Cache.RequestCachePolicy(Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache)
httpClientRequest.ContentLength = myJSON.Length
httpClientRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
httpClientRequest.Date = Date.Now
httpClientRequest.Headers.Add("Action", "PositionReport")
httpClientRequest.KeepAlive = False
httpClientRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 10
httpClientRequest.Method = "POST"
httpClientRequest.ProtocolVersion = Version.Parse("1.1")
httpClientRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy
httpClientRequest.Timeout = 5000
httpClientRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = False
httpClientRequest.UserAgent = "v" & My.Application.Info.Version.ToString
Using httpRequestStream = httpClientRequest.GetRequestStream
  httpRequestStream.Write(myJSON, 0, myJSON.Length)
  httpRequestStream.Close()
End Using
Using httpResponseStream = httpClientRequest.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
  Using reader As New IO.StreamReader(httpResponseStream)
    Dim result As String = reader.ReadToEnd
  End Using
End Using
```

myJSON() is of type byte.

Up to the first using statement, everything is fine. I can call the code a million times and no problems.  However, as soon as I start writing to, or reading from the request, the application's memory slowly but surely keeps increasing.

I am obviously missing to to dispose of something, but I am not seeing where / what I am missing?

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Add: `Using httpResponse as HttpWebResponse = httpClientRequest.GetResponse(),  responseStream as Stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), reader As New StreamReader(httpResponseStream) End Using`. Remove this: `httpClientRequest.KeepAlive = False` and this: `httpClientRequest.ProtocolVersion = Version.Parse("1.1")` (or keep them, these are both irrelevant).

Comment: Code is is missing though, since you cannot use this: `Dim result As String = reader.ReadToEnd` anywhere. So there's something else that takes that result, sends it back, elaborates it (creating other strings, possibly, or other objects). If you call `GC.Collect()` after ~`100` rounds and it's about the strings handling, you should see memory usage drop ~instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in WebRequest...

After looking at memory dumps, deep internally to the .NET 4.8 libraries, I found _SslStream.cs continuously calling s_PinnableReadBufferCache.  The list just grew bigger and bigger with every request made, and the list internally was never cleaned nor was any objects removed from the list.

This is (from what I can see), being used by the new ServicePointManager in .NET.

After migrating all my HTTP calls to the new(er) and preferred method of using Systems.Net.Http.HttpClient, everything is working flawlessly without a problem.

Not sure what is/isn't going on here, but the code works with Http.HttpClient, and not with HttpWebRequest.  HttpWebRequest can be traced back (in my case) to a list that is continuously growing in size(s_PinnableReadBufferCache), which caused the memory consumption.

Comment: this is odd, because HttpClient uses HtypWebRequest under the hood (at least on windows)